# Query join/select in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have some database like this.

```
date       name  closed
2017-01-10 room1 0
2017-01-11 room2 1
2017-01-12 room3 0
```

I want to join all the records if in column **closed** the value is `0`. If the value is `1`, I don't want to show the record.

How can I make some query to do that ?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM availability a 
WHERE a.closed = 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a query you have tried so far?

Comment: @Andrew I just have query which `where` clause. I don't know to do that.

Comment: Just on this site people don't like writing queries if you don't post what you have done so far. You could add that query you have to the Q.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew . You got to show us that you have tried something. Even if it's wrong, you got to show us that you made some effort.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: @Andrew I just edited my questions. That's what I was do yet and it still wrong.

Comment: @Yousaf please look into the questions again. I just edited my questions.

Comment: What's the name of your table ? is it `rates` ?

Comment: @Yousaf no. the name of tables is `availability`

Comment: @Antonio You are applying a `JOIN` and displaying data from more than one table. You need to mention all the tables and their names in your question of which you want to display the data.

Comment: @Yousaf Okay I just edited my questions again and I just select from one table not join anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have no where condition. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM rates r RIGHT JOIN availability a ON a.rates_id = r.rates_id where a.closed = 0 GROUP BY r.name
```

Also, the group by seems incorrect, usually you group by an ID although sometimes you will need the name. A more likely group by would be `a.rates_id` or `r.rates_id`

Answer (score 0):

you want only `closed = 0` then there are many ways to do this

```
select * from availability having closed < 1;
```

also try this

```
select * from ta where closed in (0);
```

another way

```
select * from ta where closed not in (1);
```

if you want to do using mysql joins then use this

```
select t1.* from availability t1 inner join
availability t2
on t1.closed in (0) group by t1.name;
```